# Bash script to convert part of filename from UTC to UTC+7

Tags: javascript, regex, linux, bash

I need to change the part of the files from UTC to UTC+7 with bash script in Linux

Adding 7 to the hour field. However, It will run into trouble if this takes us past midnight, in which case the day will have to be incremented and possibly the month and year.

The files are located in directories and subdirectories.

**An example of the original filename**

Video_learning_(incl._book)_443323_772233232_2020-03-19_10-32-36.mp4
Video_learning_(incl._book)_777323_226611115_2020-03-29_17-56-24.mp4

**I have successfully converted from UTC to UTC+7 and filename become**

Video_learning_(incl._book)_443323_772233232_2020-03-19_17-32-36.mp4
Video_learning_(incl._book)_777323_226611115_2020-03-30_00-56-24.mp4

I have successfully converted those file with **Advance Renamer** with the following script

```
match = item.name.match(/^(.*_)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})_(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/);
epoch = Date.parse(match[2] + 'T' + match[3] + ':' + match[4] + ':' + match[5]);
date = new Date(epoch + (7* 3600000));

return match[1] + date.getFullYear()+ "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "_" + ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
```

But need to used and modify the script to bash script and use it in Linux. The script will run if any new file or folder creation.

**I tried to modify the script as follows and run on Centos, but it is not working**

```
for file in *.mp4; do
        if [ -e "$file" ]; then
            match = item.name.match(/^(.*_)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})_(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/);
            epoch = Date.parse(match[2] + 'T' + match[3] + ':' + match[4] + ':' + match[5]);
            date = new Date(epoch + (7* 3600000));

            newfilename =  match[1] + date.getFullYear()+ "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "_" + ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

            mv "$file" "$newfilename"
        fi
done
```

Comment: What language is that? You can't switch from bash to something else in the middle of a script.

Comment: @choroba Apparently, it's Javascript. @Agus, you should either save your script in separate `.js` and run it with `node` from your bash script, or re-write it completely using proper bash syntax instead of JS.

Comment: *"`The script will run if any new file [...] creation.`"* Then you also have to identify the new files (instead using `*.mp4`) or else you will convert the already converted dates again, resulting in UTC+14 or even UTC+21, +28, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the timestamp of your files matches the time embedded into the filename as per your naming convention, you can use the timezone conversion functionality available in `ls --time-style` combined with the environment variable `TZ` to copy or rename your files:

```
#!/bin/bash
TZ=${1:-"UTC-7"}
find . -name "*.mp4" | grep -v "TIMEZONEADJUSTED" \
| while IFS= read -r filepath; do
        # In POSIX systems, a user can specify the time zone by means of the TZ environment variable:
        TZ=$TZ ls -g --time-style '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' $filepath | cut -d' ' -f5-6 \
        | while IFS=' ' read newtime filename; do
                filenamebase=${filename%_*}; filenamebase=${filenamebase%_*}
                fileextension=${filename##*\.};
                cp --verbose $filename ${filenamebase}_${newtime}_TIMEZONEADJUSTED.${fileextension}
        done
done
```

Here's the output of the script during a test run on my system:

```
~/PROJECTS/stackoverflow/tmp$ ./convert-tz.sh 
'./Video_learning_(incl._book)_443323_772233232_2020-03-19_10-32-36.mp4' -> './Video_learning_(incl._book)_443323_772233232_2020-03-19_17-32-36_TIMEZONEADJUSTED.mp4'
'./Video_learning_(incl._book)_777323_226611115_2020-03-29_17-56-24.mp4' -> './Video_learning_(incl._book)_777323_226611115_2020-03-30_00-56-24_TIMEZONEADJUSTED.mp4'
'./tmp2/Video_learning_(incl._book)_443323_772233232_2020-03-19_10-32-36.mp4' -> './tmp2/Video_learning_(incl._book)_443323_772233232_2020-03-19_17-32-36_TIMEZONEADJUSTED.mp4'
```

Note: The `TIMEZONEADJUSTED` serves as a marker that the filename has already been adjusted, so that the situation that @Socowi describes in his comment above does not happen.
Instead of a `mv`, I've put a `cp` in the script, so you can first test if the script works for you, without modifying your original files. In case that it does, you can still replace the copy with a move.